# git push -v vs. git push

Tags: git, github

I am using a new IDE with embedded github support.  locally from the command line, I can successfully use `git push orgin master` and update github.  however my IDE uses the command with a `-v` flag which is causing an error.

so i tried to go to the command line and replicate the command, and sure enough it doesn't work when I use `-v`

when I used `git push -v origin master` I get

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Does anyone know why this fails *only* when using the `-v` flag?

Comment: That's bizarre... -v should just make the output verbose.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?  The reason being is that the Windows ports are unofficial and may have bugs the Linux version doesn't.

Comment: Makes no sense. Can you do a `git help push` to see what the `-v` option does on your setup? Also, which version of git are you using?

Comment: Don't the option flags have to be at the end *after* the parameters?

Comment: phpStorm.  incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @Casey, nope. At least for me (Windows, msysgit) `git push -v origin master` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

> when I used "git push -v orgin master" I get fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Well yes, because it's supposed to be `origin`, not `orgin`.

Comment: i edited my original post.  typo when posting, but still giving the error.